# How to get public variable values if I convert a class to an object

Tags: c#, class, object

I have this class

```
class data_
{
  public string string_data;
  public int index_data;
  public data_(string s,int i)
  {
     string_data = s;
     index_data = i;
  }
}
```

now I am passing this class as an object in

```
public partial class Form1:Form
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index =0;
        foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("data"))
        {
            Threadpool(new WaitCallBack(execute,new data_(line,index))); // I am passing the class as an object here
            ++index;
        }
    }
    private void execute(object processed_data)
    {
        string text = processed_data.string_data; //error
        int index = processed_data.index_data; //error
        // work and work
    }
}
```

as you can see the class `data_` has 2 public variables that can be used and I assign their values when i start a thread but I can't do `processed_data.string_data` or `processed_data.index_data` as its getting passed as an object and WaitCallBack only accepts objects, nothing else. So how can I access `processed_data`'s 2 variables in the `execute` void?(cause it looks like those 2 variables are gone after I pass the class as an object)

Comment: `new Threadpool`? WTF?

Comment: @Dennis, sorry I accidentally wrote that :P

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the object back to your original type once you get to the new method.

```
private void execute(object processed_data)
{
    var data = (data_)processed_data;
}
```

Of course, if you are going to be doing this then you could just make the method parameter the correct type.

Comment: so can I do `data.string_data` and `data.index_data` ?

Comment: will this work? `data_ data = (data_)processed_data;`

Comment: Yes, `var` is just an implicit type declaration since it's obvious what the type is in this case.

Comment: I have tried this and its still not giving the 2 public variables, you go ahead and try

Comment: I mean post your new code that's not working. Otherwise it's very difficult for me to see why you're not getting the properties.

Comment: all right, I will comment again when I will be done.Stand by

Comment: look the class `data_` automatically gets converted into a object but then when I try to access the 2 variables from the converted object. It doesn't work

Comment: You haven't implemented the cast to `data_` as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're at least on the .NET 4 (see `File.ReadLines`), you don't need either type cast, or `ThreadPool`/`Thread`.

Assuming, that data processing of one line is independent from another line, you can use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Parallel.Foreach(File
        .ReadLines("data")
        .Select((line, index) => new data_(line, index)), execute);        
}

private void execute(data_ processed_data)
{
    // work and work
}
```

`ForEach` will use `ThreadPool` internally, but it will do it for you, and you'll pass parameters as is, without need to cast them later.

To understand, what happens undercover, I recommend you to start from these links:

- [Lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (this is for understanding, what is `=>`)
- [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) (this is for `Select`)
- [Parallel programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (this is for `Parallel.ForEach`).

Comment: can you explain it to me please :) that would help me to understand

Comment: @AKC: I've updated the answer with a number of useful links. In short, my code is almost analogous to your code, but it uses higher level of abstraction to organize parallel processing and LINQ to prepare data.

Comment: Thank you so much dennis! :D